# How to get a list of files open by some process

Tags: qnx

On mac i can do

```
sudo filebyproc.d 2>/dev/null | grep " cat "
```

running

```
cat balbalbla
```

i've got

```
sudo filebyproc.d 2>/dev/null | grep " cat "
Password:
  8    178                       open:entry cat /dev/dtracehelper
 10    964              open_nocancel:entry cat /usr/share/locale/UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
  2    178                       open:entry cat balbalbla
```

which is the list of all files open by cat process.

How to do the same (or similar) in QNX?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pidin -p <process> fds`.  `<process>` may be specified as either a pid or the name of the binary (eg. 'cat').

Ref: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/p/pidin.html

Comment: The <pid> process must already be running, right? I have a problem identifying its configuration file, which is open, loaded and closed at an early stage of pid's life. dtrace approach (i use as an example in my question) solve this, doesn't matter that "balbalbla" doesn't exists)  Unfortunately I know almost nothing about qnx. Any advice or guidance is really welcome, I am completely clueles. I already tried to play with -k and -l options of pidin, without success. If <pid> is not running, executing pidin finished immediately.

Comment: That's correct, you can't query the state of processes that don't exist.   If you're trying to trace the execution of a program, the QNX "System Analysis Toolkit", aka the kernel trace logger, is the tool to use.   Documentation is here: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.sat/topic/about.html